# Alert Login Popup -Web Driver Script

Tags: selenium

I am not sure whether selenium web driver can handle JavaScript alert/pop-up window.

I have a scenario like

1. Enter URL
2. Alert/Pop-up window will be displayed .User need to enter User name and Password and Click "OK" on window

Comment: yes, it can. Please ask a more specific question, you will get a better answer if you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle it by many ways

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(**username**, **password**));
```

OR

```
driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that `wait.until()` returns an instance with an Alert interface. Very cool! This way you can spare the `Driver.SwitchTo().Alert()`. Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting an error: `UserAndPassword cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: It will work only if pop is browser type NOT application type and also it depends which browser you are using, currently this piece of code not working properly on firefox and working on chrome.

Comment: once you varify your pop up type you can try this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358965/how-to-handle-authentication-alert-of-browser-in-selenium-webdriver/59611252#59611252